# Convert second to years, days, hours, minutes and seconds

Tags: javascript, date-parsing

help me with this one problem. I am confused how to convert second to years, days, hours, minutes and second in JavaScript. This below as an example

```
convertSeconds(10000)) // 2 hours, 46 minutes and 40 seconds
convertSeconds(62)) // 1 minutes and 2 seconds
convertSeconds(2000000)) // 23 days, 3 hours, 33 minutes and 20 seconds
convertSeconds(126144060)) // 4 years and 1 minutes
```

I know this task needs modulus just like below :

```
var days = Math.floor(seconds / (3600*24))
seconds  -= days*3600*24
var hrs   = Math.floor(seconds / 3600)
seconds  -= hrs*3600
var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60)
seconds  -= minutes*60
```

But it doesn't print as I want it like in my comments. How to console like that. Thank you

Comment: What's `convertSeconds` do? It's really very unclear to me what your question actually is.

Comment: You can just use console.log(hrs + " hours "+ minutes + " min " + seconds + " sec");

Comment: I'm sorry if it wasn't very unclear. What I meant, I wanted the answer just like my test case. If there is no hour then hour doesn't need to be printed.

Answer (score -1):

if I understand your question, the solution could be:

```
function convertSeconds(secT){ 

var seconds = secT % 60; 

var minutes = ((secT - seconds)/60) % 60; 

var hours = (secT - seconds - (minutes * 60)) / 3600 % 3600;
//EDIT
var print = "";
If(hours!=0){
    print = print + hours + " hours ";
}
if(minutes!=0){
    print = print + minutes  + " minutes ";
}
if(seconds!=0){
    print = print + seconds + " seconds ";
}
alert(print);
}
```

Comment: but the test case needed if there hours is zero then hours don't need to be printed

Comment: Add the if and you print the variables you want.

I edit the response.